# Expo calendar alarm feature won't show its 'alarm'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to implement EXPO calendar feature to show calendar app alarm to users.

I could set a new schedule in calendar app with my code but it doesn't give alarm on given time.

```
addEvent = async () => {
        var permission=await Expo.Permissions.askAsync('calendar');
    console.log(permission);
    var startDate = new Date();
    alert(startDate)
    var eventi= await Expo.Calendar.createEventAsync(Expo.Calendar.DEFAULT,{
      startDate: startDate,
      endDate: startDate,
      title: "알람",
      timeZone: "GMT-9",
      alarms:[{relativeOffset: 0, method:'Calendar.AlarmMethod.DEFAULT'}],
    })
    .then( event => {
      console.log('success',event);
        })
  .catch( error => {
      console.log('failure',error);
      });
  }
```

here's my code.

it's all good before when it comes to scheduled alarm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your users are in the timezone "GMT-9". Have you checked the created alarm in the calendar?

Comment: Yes. I'm in gmt-9(KST) and my expected users, too.

Comment: I found an answer. The reason was the 'alarms' array.
I got all past alarms and figured out the method
alarms:[{relativeOffset: 0, method:'alert}], not
alarms:[{relativeOffset: 0, method:'Calendar.AlarmMethod.DEFAULT'}]